# cmake subdirectory preprocesser include error

Tags: c++, cmake

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── lib
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Scene.cpp
    └── Scene.hpp
```

./CMakeLists.txt is like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(myapp)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(blend2d REQUIRED)
find_package(Box2D REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(lib)

include_directories(lib)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${Blend2D_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Box2D_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

link_directories(lib)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Box2D)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE blend2d)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SCENE)
```

./lib/CMakeLists.txt is like this

```
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_library(SCENE Scene.cpp Scene.hpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

The problem is in Scene.cpp, Scene.hpp

Scene.cpp is like this.

```
#include "Scene.hpp"

class Scene
{
    ...
}
```

the "#include <Scene.hpp>" makes an error that "#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit."

And Scene.hpp is like this.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
class Scene
{
    ....
}
```

the "#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>" makes an error that "cannot open opencv2/opencv.hpp"

When I ignore the error and run 'cmake --build .',
It produces

```
[25%] Linking CXX executable myapp
/usr/bin/ld: canoot find -lSCENE
```

I'm using wsl ubuntu with vscode.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the exact error messages you get.  Verbose build output would be helpful too.

Comment: @StephenNewell Thanks to your advice. I edit my post. I hope it would be useful.

Comment: You didn't provide verbose build output that shows the include errors.

Comment: @StephenNewell What is verbose build output???

Comment: The actual compilation line that generates the build error.

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue, but usually cmake keywords and variable names are all uppercase and the rest uses pascal or camel case, at least that's what I choose. As for identifying the issue in your question: Did cmake list the `SCENE` target as being built or at least checked during the build process before the error occurs?

Comment: @fabian Your comments let me fix the erroer. I didn't make libScene.a file. I have thought that just build CMakeLists.txt at root would automatically build subdirectory CMakeLists.txt, isn't it?